# why is my header not rendering in this simple angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I am new to angular, I am creating a simple app for hands on learning. I started using `shared.module.ts` to do my header and importing it in my `app.module.ts` but when I run the application, I **don't** see my `<app-header></app-header>` rendering. Below is my code, can someone tell me what is wrong? I believe I am exporting/importing/declaring things the right way they should be.

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent // exporting header component from shared module here
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
//predefined modules
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

//application modules
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {BlogModule} from './blog/blog.module';
import { SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module'

//components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent//declaring the dashboard component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BlogModule,
    SharedModule //importing the shared module here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
Hello, Header is below
<app-header></app-header>
```

**What I see on the browser:**

[image]

You can see that the header doesnt load, and there is no errors in console too.

Comment: I did not think, routing code, header component implementation code etc. is not relevant to the problem I am having here, let me know if I need to add those pieces of code as well.

Comment: Where is the header component? Header component is not in declaration.

Comment: header component is in declaration of shared.module.ts, since I want it to be part of shared components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared Dashboard component in the App module, and import here the Shared module. But you use Header component inside Dashboard component, not the App Component. It can't work.
You should use separate module for Dashboard component and import Shared module there to use Header component inside. Or just use Header component in the app.component.html.